# Windows Azure iOS Authentication

Tags: iphone, windows, azure, azure-storage

Hi Anyone help me out in this issues it would be very appreciated , and it would be better myself , please review my task.

1) I started the iOS application in the useful platform windows azure. 
2) After i successfully build the lets-started iOS Project with my own Table. 
3) I added the code snippet for user authentication and using the facebook identify but what url i have to do in facebook developer page App Domains with out i use this filed im getting below error in simulator. EROOR : Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration.

Regards ,

Shiv Suthan M

Comment: I done the activity myself with Google identify in Windows Azure

Answer (score 0):

Specific instructions for setting up Facebook auth including the URL and settings that should be used in the Facebook configuration page can be found here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-facebook-authentication/